Authorization dropped before the request reached the backend, but request in postman is 200
Authorization dropped before the request reached the backend using axios(returns "request failed with status code 401" and {"error": "Missing access token"}), but in Network authorization header is ok
If i use postman all is ok and authorization reach backend
Code example:
export const fetchContactsAxios = createAsyncThunk(
  'contacts/fetchContacts',
  async (credentials: { user_id: string; }, { getState }) => {
    try {
      axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
      const state = getState() as RootState;
      const token = state.apiAuth?.accessToken;

      if (!token) {
        throw new Error('Token not found in state');
      }

      const { user_id} = credentials;

      const headers = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        withCredentials: true,
      };

      console.log('Headers:', headers);
      console.log(
        'Request URL:',
        `${API_URL}/api/users/contacts?user_id=${user_id}`,
      );

      const response = await axios.get(
        `${API_URL}/api/users/contacts?user_id=${user_id}`,
        { headers },
      );

      console.log('Response Data:', response.data);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
        console.error('Axios error response:', error.response?.data);
      }
      console.error('Error fetching contacts:', (error as Error).message);
      throw error;
    }
  },
);

